# Is mysql_fetch_array() supported in PHP 5.2.6?

Tags: php, mysql

I get this error message when I try to use mysql_fetch_array():

```
while( $deffefgpSfet->fetch() ) {
   $roefe= mysql_fetch_array($ffefe, MYSQL_NUM);

Warning:  mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid 
         MySQL result resource in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on line 157
```

Comment: If it was not supported, you would have received an error message, not a warning.  `$blah` needs to be a result set from a mysql query.

Comment: This works on a different server though with a newer version of php and I get no warning message

Comment: It's also worth noting that warnings can be turned off in php.ini, so your other server may have suppressed warnings.

Comment: On that other server... YOu can possibly connect / there is another database version or content / `$blah` is actually a resource for whatever reason. To find out that reason, use `mysql_error` after creating `$blah`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show the code for the object $defeft but I can assume what you're trying to do...

```
$blah = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables");

if(!$blah) { // check for mysql errors
  echo mysql_error();
  exit;
}

while( $defeft = mysql_fetch_array($blah)) {

 echo $defeft['row'];

}
```

Defeft holds the rows data in a array, and while loops through each row.

Comment: do i actually put '[row]'? I get an error saying parse error in line 157

Comment: @cool_cs check the code again. you put the column name that you want the data from.

Answer (score 0):

doesn't that error refer to using mysql_fetch_X on a variable that is not a Resource, e.g. the query failed, ensure your query returns a valid result, rather than a mysql error?

```
$a = mysql_query($sql) or die();
```

try this (or similar) :)